# How to automatically insert IP address in Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I am trying to setup Xdebug on my Docker container so I'd need to automatically get the client IP (Mac and Linux) and this should be printed in my Dockerfile, what I've done so far

```
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
  && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_host=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

line 5 should get the IP address from my client but it does not work, any idea? If you follow a different approach I am more than happy to hear how.

Comment: Not sure why you'd need `remote_host`  when you have `remote_connect_back`.

Comment: if I don't need it, even better, I added it in an attempt to make it work. do you see any other parameter not needed or missing?

Comment: This isn't something you'd typically do in a Dockerfile.  What if you wanted to run the same image on a different host with a different host IP address?

Comment: that's why I wanted to do it automatically...

Comment: @user3174311 The rest look okay I think? But just removing the line seems to address your question. If you're still having problems, might be worth asking a new question with the issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy you need to create a bash file. for example build.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm .env
if [ ! -f .env ]; then
myip=
while IFS=$': \t' read -a line ;do
    [ -z "${line%inet}" ] && ip=${line[${#line[1]}>4?1:2]} &&
        [ "${ip#127.0.0.1}" ] && myip=$ip
  done< <(LANG=C /sbin/ifconfig)
    touch .env
    echo IP=$myip >> .env
fi
```

run bash file and in docker-compose file, use it with ${IP} , like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    build: ./DockerFiles/Worker
    ports:
    - ${IP}:81
```